# Server response 400 when uploading files using Powershell or cURL

Tags: powershell, curl, post, automation, upload

I am having trouble creating an automation script to upload CSV files to a webserver using tokens for authentication. Initially, I tried using cURL but received the following message: "LogError : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request". I spent hours trying to troubleshoot the issue but was unsuccessful, so I switched to PowerShell. Unfortunately, I received the same error.

Here is my cURL script:

```
$file = "c:\folder\file.csv"
$machinetoken = $companySettings.EncryptionToken

curl -Uri https:https://site/upload/files -Method Post -Headers @{"Authorization" = $($machinetoken)} -InFile $file -Verbose
```

Here is the error message I received from cURL:

```
LogError : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

Additionally, here is the PowerShell script I used:

```
try {
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Post' -Uri $endpoint -Headers $headers -InFile $file
}
catch {
    $errorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    if (Get-Member -InputObject $_.Exception -Name 'Response') {
        try {
            $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
            $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
            $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
            $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
            $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd();
        } catch {
            Throw "An error occurred while calling REST method at: $url. Error: $errorMessage. Cannot get more information."
        }
    }
    Throw "An error occurred while calling REST method at: $endpoint. Error: $errorMessage. Response body: $responseBody"
}
```

And here is the error message I received from PowerShell:

```
An error occurred while calling REST method at: https://site/upload/files. Message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.. Response body: result_code=NOT_MULTIPART
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Not all server are the same.  Each server requires a different HTTP headers and body format.  Without knowing the servers requirements this question cannot be solved unless you want us to guess.

Comment: Is it possible to acquire this information by querying the server or is it necessary to contact the hosting provider in order to obtain it?

Comment: You need to contact the hosting provider or find documentation on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on Reddit:

"PowerShell 6.1 or later, Invoke-RestMethod has the new -Form parameter that automatically deals with all of the MultipartFormDataContent stuff for you. It also has -SkipCertificateCheck so you don't have to deal with ServicePointManager. It also defaults to using the latest TLS versions, but you also have the -SslProtocol parameter if needed"
[Read full thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/cxxrc7/invokerestmethod_to_upload_file_in/)

I change my script and upgraded Powershell to version 7.3.4 and it worked!

```
$machinetoken = "fsdfadfadgadgfdagfgdfgadgfaf"
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", $($machinetoken))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
$headers.Add("Cookie", "XXXXxxxxXX;xxXXXxxxxXX")

$multipartContent = [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]::new()
$multipartFile = $path
$FileStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($multipartFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$fileHeader = [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue]::new("form-data")
$fileHeader.Name = "report_data"
$fileHeader.FileName = "C:\blabla\filename.txt"
$fileContent = [System.Net.Http.StreamContent]::new($FileStream)
$fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $fileHeader
$multipartContent.Add($fileContent)

$body = $multipartContent

$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://site/report' -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers -Body $body
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I first got it to work in Postman. When I received status code "200" I used the "Code" function that was showing what kind of information was needed to get the script going.